# numpy vectorized sum over outer products?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have two float arrays in python numpy: `A` of shape (60000,) and `B` of shape (60000,784). I attempted the following operation:

```
np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',A,B[:,:,np.newaxis]*B[:,np.newaxis,:])
```

but it produces an out of memory error, because creating an array of shape (60000,784,784) in the intermediate step would require 137GB of RAM.

I tried the following alternative way to do that:

```
S=np.zeros((784,784))
for a,b in izip(A,B):
    S+=a*np.outer(b,b)
```

but the explicit python sum is way too slow.

Is there a numpy way of doing that, using a vectorized function to have fast performance, but without generating any (60000,784,784) shape arrays in intermediate steps?

Comment: For performance, try with the parameter `optimize=True` for `np.einsum`. It is not optimized by default (unfortunately). It may also use a bit less memory. Still, when the array is too big, you need to split the computation in multiple chunks, including for einsum. Alternative, you can use Numba+loops to speed up the computation in the second code. The later is certainly *much* better here.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I don't think `optimize=True` would help much if it's the multiplication in the argument that's the heavy operation..?

Comment: @AKX I thought that the "intermediate step" was in einsum here (internal temporary arrays of einsum due to the chosen path), but I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can simplify the path and then it doesn't require that big of an intermediate array.

But don't forget the `optimize=True`, otherwise it is quite slow.

```py
import numpy as np

a, b = 60, 784

A = np.random.rand(a)
B = np.random.rand(a, b)

R = np.einsum("i,ijk->jk", A, B[:, :, np.newaxis] * B[:, np.newaxis, :], optimize=True)
R2 = np.einsum("i,ij,ik->jk", A, B, B, optimize=True)

np.allclose(R, R2)  # True
```

Performance is quite good on my machine:

```py
In [1]: a, b = 60_000, 784
   ...: A = np.random.rand(a)
   ...: B = np.random.rand(a, b)
   ...:
   ...: %timeit R = np.einsum("i,ij,ik->jk", A, B, B, optimize=True)
641 ms ± 32.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```